# Why does a variable assignment not throw a ReferenceError when the variable is not defined - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've tried this in Chrome, Opera, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox and still gotten the same case: A `ReferenceError` exception is **not thrown** that the variable I assigned a value is not defined.

---

The syntax is:

```
// Where `identifier_name` was not formally declared/ initialized.
(function() {})(identifier_name = 2)
```

---

Why does this behavior occur?

***Edit:*** Just to add, this doesn't work if what is being assigned is a property of an object i.e.:

```
// Throws a ReferenceError that `object_name` is not defined.
(function() {})(object_name.property_name = 2)
```

Comment: It just creates a global variable in that case.

Comment: you haven't put a keyword in front of it, like `const` `var` or `let` so it'll be global

Comment: It will throw a ReferenceError if you run it in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats what we used to call the [horror of implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

You basically create a global variable by accident. You can `"use strict";`mode to prevent that.

Your second snippet does not work because you are trying to access a variable that was not declared yet, which is different from assigning to a variable that was not declared already (cause that implicitly declares the variable).

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a global variable here in both cases without the 'var' keyword.

Comment: Yes, and that was the oddity here. Implicit globals: Declaring variables on the global scope without the `.` operator, or the `const`, `let`/ `var` keywords.

The best part? Does not cause an error except in Strict Mode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).